# SQL - aggregate some columns and map id to specific column

Tags: sql, oracle

so i have a query that returns this.

[image]

now I want to create a query that will aggregate this to get a result like this..

[image]

I tried aggregation but section name displays the wrong value

```
select max(id), max(receipt_id), max(section_id), max(section_name) from t;
```

[image]

how can i map section_id to return its corresponding section_name??
turns out max returns biggest value.. in case of strings, it returns the longest.

thank you.

Comment: Could you explain the logic here to get the last record ?

Comment: last record should be based on maximum section_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
select qry.*, tbl.section_name 
from 
  tbl, (select max(id) id, max(receipt_id) receipt_id, max(section_id) section_id from tbl) qry
where tbl.section_id = qry.section_id
```

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=feb3965fa96e1a2ac9194173e136cf09

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below -

```
select t1.id,t1.receipt_id,t1.section_id,section_name 
from t inner join
(
select max(id) as id, max(receipt_id) as receipt_id, max(section_id) as section_id
from t
)t1 on t.section_id=t1.section_id
```